# Parse Json into POJO using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

I have the following json

```
{
    "root": {
        "status": "UP",
        "connection1": {
            "status": "UP"
        },
        "connection2": {
            "status": "UP"
        }
    }
}
```

Also i have the following POJO classes i want to convert JSON into

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class POJO {

    @JsonProperty("root")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = RootDeserializer.class)
    private Root root;

    //getters + setters
}

public class Root {

    private boolean isAlive;
    private List<Connection> connections;

    public Root(boolean isAlive, List<Connection> connections) {
        this.isAlive = isAlive;
        this.connections = connections;
    }

    //getters + setters
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Connection {

    private String status;

    //getters + setters
}
```

And finally i have this deserializer to convert json into Root instance

```
public class RootDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Root> {

    private static final String CONNECTION_PREFIX = "connection";
    private static final String UP_STATUS = "UP";

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public Root deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        Map<String, Map<String, Object>> rootJsonMap = parser.readValueAs(Map.class);

        boolean isAlive = StringUtils.equals(UP_STATUS, String.valueOf(rootJsonMap.get("status")));
        List<Connection> connections = rootJsonMap.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(entry -> StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(entry.getKey(), CONNECTION_PREFIX))
                .map(this::mapToConnection)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return new Root(isAlive, connections);
    }

    private PosServerConnection mapToConnection(Map.Entry<String, Map<String, Object>> entry) {
        Map<String, Object> connectionJsonMap = entry.getValue();
        return objectMapper.convertValue(connectionJsonMap, Connection.class);
    }
}
```

This way i can group all my Connections into one List in Root class. 
My question is there any another way to do this ??

I'd like to do this without such big deserializer using just Jackson annotations on my Pojo classes

Comment: Yes, there are other ways to do this. --- [Why is “Is there a way to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273/202153) --- *(FYI: I'm not the down-voter)*

Comment: @Andreas ok. i edit my question

Comment: Yeah, you edited the question text, but you didn't improve the *question*. You just added a statement of what you like, but the question remains the same, so the answer remains the same: Yes, there are other ways to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply achieve this by using `@JsonAnySetter` annotation for customizing `Setter` for `List<Connection>` as follows. You can also reference to [Jackson Annotation Examples](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations) to see how it works.

**POJOs**

```
public class Pojo {
    private Root root;

    //general getters, setters and toString
}

public class Root {
    private String status;
    private List<Connection> connections = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Connection> getConnections() {
        return connections;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setConnections(String name, Connection connection) {
        connection.setName(name);
        this.connections.add(connection);
    }

    //other getters, setters and toString
}

public class Connection {
    private String name;
    private String status;

    //general getters, setters and toString
}
```

Then you can serialize the given JSON string to `Pojo` with common way by `Jackson`:

**Code Snippet**

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Pojo pojo = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, Pojo.class);
System.out.println(pojo.getRoot().getConnections().toString());
```

**Console output**

```
[Connection [name=connection1, status=UP], Connection [name=connection2, status=UP]]
```